# use value from a subquery

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I have a subquery in the SELECT clause

```
SELECT a, b, (SELECT count(*) FROM X) AS Total, Total / 2
FROM Y
WHERE ... ;
```

The error says "Invalid column name Total".

How can I store result of the subquery in a variable named 'Total' so that I don't need to repeat my subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in another query:

```
SELECT a, b, Total, Total / 2 FROM (
  SELECT a, b, (SELECT count(*) FROM X) AS Total
  FROM Y
  WHERE ...) Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the result of aggregate function in same query. You need to write outer query to further evaluate result of aggregate function.

You can try following:

```
select a,b,Total / 2 FROM
(
SELECT a, b, (SELECT count(*) FROM X) AS Total
FROM Y
WHERE ... ) As FinalTable
```